# JQGrid - How Can We make an Custom Row Detail

Tags: jqgrid, subgrid

Some one give me the some Sample Code to make my Grid like this.I read in document that jqgrid just supports subgrid.

like this page in Hierachy http://trirand.net/demoaspnetmvc.aspx

thanks !

Answer (score 17):

On the page [Custom Row Detail](http://www.trirand.net/aspnetmvc/grid/hierarchycustomrowdetails) you can see how you can use [subGridRowExpanded](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:subgrid#events) event handle to show custom HTML data as subgrid data. In general if you have any standard jqGrid you can implement the same very easy. You should just add `subGrid: true` to the grid and define `subGridRowExpanded` which append html to the subgrid:

```
subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
    var html = "<span>Some HTML text which corresponds the row with id="+
               row_id + "</span><br/>";
    $("#" + subgrid_id).append(html);
}
```

You can see this live [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SubGrid.htm):

Comment: Is it possible to remove the first column from the subgrid? Removing the first column of the parent grid is easy but I can't find a way to remove the column from the subgrid easily. Is there an easy way of doing it (using the example on this page)?