# jqGrid: Customize row display

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, subgrid

Is it possible to use subgrid without url?
Because I want to display data under my row, but this data doesn't need to come from an ajax call. It's just a label in different color depending of the row.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you would use [subGridRowExpanded](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:subgrid#events) event handler you can full specify the contain of the div which will be shown under the row after the expanded row. See very old [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SubGrid.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114498/jqgrid-how-can-we-make-an-custom-row-detail/4115481#4115481):

[image]

So you can for example follow to the [subgrid as grid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:subgrid_as_grid) example but use `datatype:'local'` and `data` parameter for the subgrid instead of the `url`.

Comment: Thank you, I will try but I think it's a good solution. I didn't know we could use datatype:'local'