# How to add items in listbox dynamically during Inline editing in jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

Does jqGrid have the capability to have an inline List control with an option to add items related to particular record. Please see the red highlighted section in the picture here: http://screencast.com/t/63632xwUi8G

[image]

I am planning on developing an ASP .NET MVC 4 application. If this is not possible please suggest one that can support this.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean under "inline editing formatter". Which element on the picture you want to have during inline editing? It would be better it you mark the element with another color. In general jqGrid allows to use other plugins to initialize inline elements. Typically one creates `<input>` and `<select>` elements initially and calls some plugin like [select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) which convert select to more "advanced" input element. [Another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10851429/315935) shows the usage on multiselect plugin.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, I have updated my question.

How do we change the column-wise arrangement in jqGrid? notice that in the screenshot the highlighted area is still part of the same row.

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't follow you. The highlighted area seems be quite other as the main information in the other rows. HTML tables can't wrap rows. Moreover one should clear distinguish between *displaying* the information in the grid from *editing* of a row of the grid. The picture contains many elements with inline selects or other controls. It looks like the user started (but not finished) of editing *multiple rows*. In jqGrid the user can start editing of row and then either save the current changes or discard there. Morover sorting by column content is blocked in inline editing mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer. The ability to add some textbox (or any html for that matter) lies in the use of sub-grids. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6276307/2920067) solves the issue.