# how to add a message to jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Is there way to add a message to jqgrid instead of subgrid?

in normal jqgrid which has subgrids, when user click on expand button it shows the subgrid

like that instead of subgrid is it possible to add a message?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add **any information** on expanding of the subgrid. You should just implement the corresponding behavior in your [subGridRowExpanded](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:subgrid#events) event handler. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SubGrid.htm) as an example from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114498/jqgrid-how-can-we-make-an-custom-row-detail/4115481#4115481).