# jqGrid does not clear subgrids when calling "clearGridData"

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using version 4.2 of jqGrid.
All goes well till the point I need to load new data on the grid.
On the first round, the grid is empty and I load some rows and each has a subgrid with some more rows.
On the second round (completely different data), the top level rows change as expected but the subgrids remain from the previous round.
I load the data on my own, and feed it to the grid using `addRowData()`, so jqGrid datatype is  `local`.

I tried `$("#grid").jqGrid("clearGridData")`  and `$("#grid").jqGrid("clearGridData").trigger("reloadGrid")` but neither works.

thanks!

Comment: You should include more full code which you use. Subgrids supports only `subgridtype: "json"` and `subgridtype: "xml"`, no 'local' datatype. Do you use probably subgrid as grid and not subgrid? How exactly? You should provide more code and probably the test data which can be used to reproduce the described problem.

Comment: @Oleg - not sure if the local datatype is supported, but it seems to work - http://jsfiddle.net/amorris/MZ9ue/

Comment: @Adam: Please read carefully: **Subgrids supports only subgridtype: "json" and subgridtype: "xml", no 'local' datatype** and later **you use probably subgrid as grid and not subgrid**. If you use *subgrid as grid* you create **manually** the content. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SubGrid.htm) from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4115481/315935). So without posting the code of `subGridRowExpanded` one can't examine the problem. The subgrid use `subGridModel` on the other side and support only `'json'` and `'xml'`. All this is because of the mix in terminology.

Comment: @Adam: You are welcome! In your answer you ask the same question as I did. I find unhappy that for both "subgrid" and "subgrid as grid" one use frequently one word "subgrid". In my opinion it's terminology problem in jqGrid documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you're loading your data - you can call a function from the subGridRowExpanded function parameter to load your data.

Here is a jsfiddle showing this (I load all subgrids with the same data)... apologies if it's a bit confusing, but it was hacked from another example.

http://jsfiddle.net/amorris/MZ9ue/

Comment: It's exactly the problem! The question is about the problem to clear the data from subgrid, but gives no information *how* the subgrid are filled.