# jqGrid remove column headers from subgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using `jqGrid-4.4.1` subGrid functionality.

In my case I want to remove Column headers from **subGrid** for each row.

I tried

```
var grid = $("#list");
var gview = grid.parents("div.ui-jqgrid-view"); 
gview.children("div.ui-jqgrid-hdiv").hide();
```

from this [link](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/treegrid/removing-column-header-row/). But, It removes header of main table, rather than subgrid.

I found an alternative but its HTML based.
[How to remove the table column headers from Jqgrid subgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839824/how-to-remove-the-table-column-headers-from-jqgrid-subgrid)

Also, How can I to remove carot sign  the from the first column when row is expanded.

Here is the snapshot. I want to remove the border marked red.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general you use the correct way to hide the column headers. The only problem is that you need to use hiding with the correct grid. Typically one creates subgrid as grid inside of `subGridRowExpanded` callback. jqGrid create `<div>` where you should place new subgrid. The `id` of the div you get as the first parameter of `subGridRowExpanded` callback (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:subgrid_as_grid#definition) for more details). So one creates subgrid with some id constructed typically based on the id of the div. If you would use *the id of the subgrid* instead of `#list` you will be able to hide the column headers of the subgrid.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SubgridWithLocalGridAndHiddenColumnHeaders.htm) demonstrate such implementation:

[image]

Below is the code which I used for [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SubgridWithLocalGridAndHiddenColumnHeaders.htm)

```js
var myData = [
        {
            id: "10",
            c1: "My Value 1",
            c2: "My Value 1.1",
            subgridData: [
                { id: "10", c1: "aa", c2: "ab" },
                { id: "20", c1: "ba", c2: "bb" },
                { id: "30", c1: "ca", c2: "cb" }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: "20",
            c1: "My Value 2",
            c2: "My Value 2.1",
            subgridData: [
                { id: "10", c1: "da", c2: "db" },
                { id: "20", c1: "ea", c2: "eb" },
                { id: "30", c1: "fa", c2: "fb" }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: "30",
            c1: "My Value 3",
            c2: "My Value 3.1",
            subgridData: [
                { id: "10", c1: "ga", c2: "gb" },
                { id: "20", c1: "ha", c2: "hb" },
                { id: "30", c1: "ia", c2: "ib" }
            ]
        }
    ],
    $grid = $("#list"),
    mainGridPrefix = "s_";

$grid.jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    data: myData,
    colNames: ["Column 1", "Column 2"],
    colModel: [
        { name: "c1", width: 180 },
        { name: "c2", width: 180 }
    ],
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [5, 10, 20],
    pager: "#pager",
    gridview: true,
    ignoreCase: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    sortname: "c1",
    viewrecords: true,
    autoencode: true,
    height: "100%",
    idPrefix: mainGridPrefix,
    subGrid: true,
    subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridDivId, rowId) {
        var $subgrid = $("<table id='" + subgridDivId + "_t'></table>"),
            pureRowId = $.jgrid.stripPref(mainGridPrefix, rowId);

        $subgrid.appendTo("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(subgridDivId));
        $subgrid.jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            data: $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", pureRowId).subgridData,
            colModel: [
                { name: "c1", width: 178 },
                { name: "c2", width: 178 }
            ],
            height: "100%",
            rowNum: 10000,
            autoencode: true,
            gridview: true,
            idPrefix: rowId + "_"
        });
        $subgrid.closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view")
            .children("div.ui-jqgrid-hdiv")
            .hide();
    }
});
$grid.jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", {add: false, edit: false, del: false});
```

**UPDATED**: [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14265456/315935) shows how to implement resizing of columns of subgrid after resizing of the columns of the main grid.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the reply. But this also removes main header. I want to keep header of main grid.

Comment: @HardikMishra: Sorry, it was typing error. One should use `$subgrid.closest` instead of `$subgrid.parents`. I modified the answer and the demo.

Comment: Hi Oleg.. If possible can you provide any pointers on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216113/resize-subgrid-columns-on-resizing-main-grid