# Resize SubGrid Columns on resizing main grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using below sample code to create jqGrid with subGrids.

In my case, I have removed headers of subGrids. So, It looks like a grouping.

Here, Whenever I resize main grid column. I checked jqGrid docs and found "**resizeStop**" which returns column id and new width.

But, didn't find anything like setSize for column.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>SubGrid Editable</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.3.2/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<style>
    .groupColumn {
            background-color: #E3E3D7 !important;
            border: 1px solid #F4F4e5;
            font-weight: bold; !important;
    }
    .lockedColumn {
            background-color: #E3E3D7 !important;
            border: 1px solid #F4F4e5;
    }
    .ui-jqgrid .ui-subgrid td.subgrid-data {
        border-top: 0 none !important;
        border-right: 0 none !important;
        border-bottom: 0 none !important;
    }

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
    $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    /*global $ */
    /*jslint browser: true, eqeq: true, plusplus: true */
    $(function () {
        "use strict";
        var colModelData =[{"classes":"groupColumn","name":"itemName","editable":false, "width":"80"},{"width":"80","name":"24394","editable":true},{"width":"80","name":"24390","editable":true},{"width":"80","name":"24387","editable":true},{"width":"80","name":"24386","editable":true},{"width":"80","name":"24385","editable":true},{"width":"80","name":"24383","editable":true},{"width":"80","name":"24369","editable":true},{"width":"80","name":"24306","editable":true}],
            colNamesArray = ["Name","12/21/2012","12/10/2012","12/03/2012","11/27/2012","11/15/2012","11/12/2012","11/09/2012","10/15/2012"],
         editableRows = [0],

         myData = [{"id":"group1","itemName":"Goal Scored","subGridData":[{"id":0,"itemName":"Cristiano Ronaldo","24369":"2","24387":"1","24394":"3","24306":"0","24390":"0","24385":"4","24386":"2","24383":"1"}]},
         {"id":"group2","itemName":"Yellow Cards","subGridData":[{"id":0,"itemName":"Cristiano Ronaldo","24369":"0","24387":"1","24394":"2","24306":"0","24390":"0","24385":"2","24386":"0","24383":"0"}]}];

        $("#list").jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            data: myData,
            colNames: colNamesArray,
            colModel: colModelData,
            gridview: true,
            height: "100%",
            width: "100%",
            caption: "Create subgrid from local data",
            subGrid: true,
             subGridOptions: {
                    reloadOnExpand: false,
                    selectOnExpand: false
                },
            subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridDivId, parentRowId) {
                    var $subgrid = $("<table id='" + subgridDivId + "_t'></table>");
                    $subgrid.appendTo("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(subgridDivId));
                    var data = $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", parentRowId);
                    $subgrid.jqGrid({
                            datatype: "local",
                            data: $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", parentRowId).subGridData,
                            colModel:colModelData,
                            height: "100%",
                            autoencode: true,
                            gridview: true
                    });

            $subgrid.closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view")
                    .children("div.ui-jqgrid-hdiv").hide();
            }, gridComplete: function(){
                    $("#list").jqGrid("expandSubGridRow","group1");
            }   

        });

    });
//]]>
</script>
```

Screen:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You question is very interesting, but the answer isn't easy. Nevertheless I invested some time and provide you [the following demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SubgridWithLocalGridAndHiddenColumnHeaders1.htm) which shows how you can implement the solution. The implementation are based on the analyse of [the source code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.base.js#L795-L830) of internal function `dragEnd` which will be called inside of `mouseup` callback (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.base.js#L2613-L2616)). `mousemove` callback (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.base.js#L2609-L2611)) and `mousedown` on the column headers (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.base.js#L2341-L2346)) play all together.

As the result [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SubgridWithLocalGridAndHiddenColumnHeaders1.htm) adjust the size of the column of the subgrid:

[image]

I included in the demo the trick with resizing of the whole grid after resizing of the column. It is described originally in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9599685/315935). I use personally it in every my productive grid because I prefer to have grids without scroll bars.

Below I include full code (all from the `document.ready` handler) of the demo:

```js
var myData = [
        {
            id: "10",
            c1: "My Value 1.1",
            c2: "My Value 1.2",
            c3: "My Value 1.3",
            c4: "My Value 1.4",
            subgridData: [
                { id: "10", c1: "aa", c2: "ab", c3: "ac", c4: "ad" },
                { id: "20", c1: "ba", c2: "bb", c3: "bc", c4: "bd" },
                { id: "30", c1: "ca", c2: "cb", c3: "cc", c4: "cd" }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: "20",
            c1: "My Value 2.1",
            c2: "My Value 2.2",
            c3: "My Value 2.3",
            c4: "My Value 2.4",
            subgridData: [
                { id: "10", c1: "da", c2: "db", c3: "dc", c4: "dd" },
                { id: "20", c1: "ea", c2: "eb", c3: "ec", c4: "ed" },
                { id: "30", c1: "fa", c2: "fb", c3: "fc", c4: "fd" }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: "30",
            c1: "My Value 3.1",
            c2: "My Value 3.2",
            c3: "My Value 3.3",
            c4: "My Value 3.4",
            subgridData: [
                { id: "10", c1: "ga", c2: "gb", c3: "gc", c4: "gd" },
                { id: "20", c1: "ha", c2: "hb", c3: "hc", c4: "hd" },
                { id: "30", c1: "ia", c2: "ib", c3: "ic", c4: "id" }
            ]
        }
    ],
    mainGridPrefix = "s_";

$("#list").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    data: myData,
    colNames: ["Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3", "Column 4"],
    colModel: [
        { name: "c1", width: 100 },
        { name: "c2", width: 130 },
        { name: "c3", width: 150 },
        { name: "c4", width: 170 }
    ],
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [5, 10, 20],
    pager: "#pager",
    gridview: true,
    ignoreCase: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    sortname: "c1",
    viewrecords: true,
    autoencode: true,
    height: "100%",
    idPrefix: mainGridPrefix,
    subGrid: true,
    subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridDivId, rowId) {
        var $subgrid = $("<table id='" + subgridDivId + "_t'></table>"),
            pureRowId = $.jgrid.stripPref(mainGridPrefix, rowId),
            colModel = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");

        $subgrid.appendTo("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(subgridDivId));
        $subgrid.jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            data: $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", pureRowId).subgridData,
            colModel: [
                { name: "c1", width: (colModel[2].width - 2) },
                { name: "c2", width: colModel[3].width },
                { name: "c3", width: colModel[4].width },
                { name: "c2", width: (colModel[5].width - 2) }
            ],
            height: "100%",
            rowNum: 10000,
            autoencode: true,
            gridview: true,
            idPrefix: rowId + "_"
        });
        $subgrid.closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view")
            .children("div.ui-jqgrid-hdiv")
            .hide();
    },
    resizeStop: function (newWidth, index) {
        // grid.dragEnd()
        var widthChange = this.newWidth - this.width,
            $theGrid = $(this.bDiv).find(">div>.ui-jqgrid-btable"),
            $subgrids = $theGrid.find(">tbody>.ui-subgrid>.subgrid-data>.tablediv>.ui-jqgrid>.ui-jqgrid-view>.ui-jqgrid-bdiv>div>.ui-jqgrid-btable");
        $subgrids.each(function () {
            var grid = this.grid;
            // we have subgrids which have no internal subgrids
            // it reduce the number of columns to 1
            // we have rownumbers: true in the main grid, but not in subgrids
            // it reduce the number of columns to additional 1
            // so we should use (index - 2) as the column index in the subgrids
            grid.resizing = { idx: (index - 2) };
            grid.headers[index - 2].newWidth = (index - 2 === 0) || (index - 1 === grid.headers.length) ? newWidth - 2 : newWidth;
            grid.newWidth = grid.width + widthChange;
            grid.dragEnd.call(grid);
            $(this).jqGrid("setGridWidth", grid.newWidth, false);
        });
        $theGrid.jqGrid("setGridWidth", this.newWidth, false);
    }
}).jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", {add: false, edit: false, del: false});
```

**UPDATED**: [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20030652/315935) introduces new `setColWidth` method based on the code of the above solution. One use new `setColWidth` method to simplify the code of `resizeStop`.

Comment: This is awesome.Thanks a ton for your time. Earlier, I saw your answer on resizing grid on resize  a column. But in this case tricky part was to find all subGrids and its first column. You made my weekend cheerful :)

Comment: Is it possible not to resize whole grid based on column resize ? I want behavior like one of your example http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooser1.htm