# jqGrid dynamic shrinkToFit depending on column number

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid in my project with the width set to 900px and the same configuration for all grids.

If I have 4 columns with the width set for each one and the option `shrinkToFit` is set to true, the columns will stretch to fit the 900px.

But if I have a second grid with 14 columns and I set the width to each one, the jqGrid won't respect the column's width because `shrinkToFit` is set to true. If I set it to false, I solve this problem. But another problem came up. The first grid now is taking the width 150px to each column and the columns are not stretching to fit the grid anymore.

Question:
Is there a way to achieve horizontal scrollbars when the sum of the columns width is bigger than the grid width without change the configuration?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand which behavior of column width and grid width calculation you lake to have. Do you want specify the column width in pixel of you want to set only proportions of width of columns and specify the total width of grid instead? Do you want to have fixed width of the grid (like have 900px for example) or you want that the width of the grid will be the sum of widths of the columns specified in pixel?

Comment: Oleg, I like to have the grid width fixed (900px). If the sum of column's width > 900px, then shrinkToFit:false. Else, shrinkToFit:true. I've made a workaround to achieve this. I'd like to know if there's such a option in jqGrid.

Comment: I only want to shrink the grid if the sum of the column's width < grid width.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand your problem. If you create grid you specify the `colModel` as parameter. You can loop though the items of the `colModel` *before* creating of the grid and calculate the sum of column's width. Depend of the value of the sum you can specify the value of `shrinkToFit`. I suppose that you do have another problem and just described your problem not quite correctly.

Comment: What is the value which you specify as `width` in `colModel`: the value in pixel of the proportion like % from 100?

Comment: I've calculated the sum of the width. This is the workaround that I'm talking about. I just want to know if there's a native way to do this, without looping through the colModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but it's very difficult to understand which exactly behavior you would like to have.

First of all you have to decide whether you know which width of the columns of the grid is the best or you want to have scaling (stretching) of the columns and the column width will be interpreted just as weight. If you want the last behavior you should choose default setting `shrinkToFit: true`. In the case the values of the `width` 100, 200 and 300 means absolutely the same as the values 1, 2 and 3.

I personally have in the practice mostly grids with many columns. So the usage of default setting `shrinkToFit: true` on a small monitor with follow large squeezing of columns. So one will not really able to see any helpful information on the grid. So I prefer to use `shrinkToFit: false` in the case. I know which is responsible width in pixel for every column and set the values as `width` during grid creating. So the users with large monitor see all of the most important information directly. Moreover I don't specify any `width` parameter for the grid. The user uses scroll bars of the page if needed. Your requirements could be different and which should choose what the value is the best for you.

If you still would prefer to use `shrinkToFit: true`, but do use some other value of the width as the sum of all widths of the grid you have one more option. **You can use `setGridWidth` method. It has optional second boolean parameter `shrink`**. The usage of `setGridWidth` method with one parameter will make shrinking based on the value of `shrinkToFit` option of the grid, but explicit usage of second `shrink` parameter allows you to change the width *without* shrinking. Probably it's wnat you want to implement.

One more option I described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14265456/315935). jqGrid don't have any method which allows to change the width of some column of the grid to the new value. In the answer I described workaround (see the code of `resizeStop` callback from the answer) which uses internal `dragEnd` method for changing the coloumn width. The demo will be used for subgrid, but the same approach one can use for every grid.