# how to set column width in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I need to set width of column in jQgrid Dynamically.
When resize column we need to store that width in session and on loading page again we have to set that width dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

There are no method for setting of `width` dynamically, but one can modify the code of `resizeStop` which I published in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14265456/315935) to create the corresponding method. In [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SubgridWithLocalGridAndHiddenColumnHeaders1.htm) the column width of subgrid will be changed based on the column width if the main grid. So the code of `resizeStop` callback just *set width of some column of grid (subgrid in the case) to new value*. It's exactly what one need for setting of `width` dynamically.

If you need just save the column with for the page and to use the last width choice of the user at the next loading of the same page then you can *create* the grid with the corresponding width of every column. Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ColumnChooserAndLocalStorage2_single.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8547852/315935) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8436273/315935). If you change the column width of some columns and reload the page you will see the grid with last changed widths. I think it's what you can use.

Comment: What is your suggested method for passing saved grid settings? I"m looking at saving some grid configurations for users and would you have some thoughts on saving those settings in a database and then passing them down in the View (MS MVC)?

Comment: @Mark: I use `localStorage` of web browser instead. So the user can have different settings on different computers or in different web browsers on the same computer. After analyzing of exact requirements of my customers saving of the information in the database was not really required.

Comment: I didn't even know about this concept... after some research this is amazing... and will allow me to add a ton of customization options for my users grids.  You are the man!

Comment: @Mark: I'm glad that you like it. The usage of `localStorage` is simple enough and it allows to improve user experience without large investment.

Comment: @Oleg thanx for your answer.But what if I need to store this data in session & restore it from session instead of local storage.

Comment: @NIKUNJSANGHADIA: Could you specify more clear what is storing the data in session? It depends very hard from the implementation. One saves in the session typically the information which can be hold *on the server side only* and uses in sequential responds to the same user. If we speak about *pure client solution* jqGrid then saving it in session has no sense. One can save it in cookie, but it has many disadvantages which I described in the answer which I referenced.

Comment: @Oleg: Actually I want to save column width of a grid for every user & I successfully did that also,But when I fetch that stored column width and reset it in jqgrid it does not show any effect in my grid.

Comment: @NIKUNJSANGHADIA: What is your question now? I understand that your code till not work, but you don't post the code here. [In the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ColumnChooserAndLocalStorage2_single.htm) which I referenced the width are saved and restore. You can examine the code and do the same. [In another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SubgridWithLocalGridAndHiddenColumnHeaders1.htm) I shown how column in subgrid can be resazed based on new value from main grid (just open subgrid and resize some column in main grid). You can follow the approach too.