# how to save the width of jqgrid columns permanently at the time of re-sizing (re-size )?

Tags: jqgrid

i want to save the width of coumns of jqgrid, when user re-size the column the width should be saved, so next time when user open the page the width should be the same user did. is it possible?

js code

```
{ name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', width:100, align: "left", sorttype: 'text', resizable: true, editable: true, editrules: { required: true } },
```

i have tried `shrinkToFit:false,` `autowidth:false`

any idea, any suggestion will be appreciated...i will mark it as answer if it works for me

thank. if you need any extra information about the code i am here to explain..just comment ;)

Answer (score 2):

jqGrid don't provide any API to change the column width after the grid been created, but I created the plugin which do this. You can download `jQuery.jqGrid.setColWidth.js` from [here](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins), included it after jqGrid JavaScript files and then you can just use new `setColWidth` method in the form

```js
$("#grid").jqGrid("setColWidth", colNameIrIndex, newWidth);
```

The method `setColWidth` will adjust the total grid width after changing the width of the column. If you don't need it you ca add `false` as an additional last parameter of `setColWidth`:

```js
$("#grid").jqGrid("setColWidth", colNameIrIndex, newWidth, false);
```

Additional details about the method you will find in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20030652/315935) and in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14265456/315935).

Probably you can write your code so that the width of columns will be set *before* the grid will be created. In the case you will don't nee the method `setColWidth`. For example you can try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ColumnChooserAndLocalStorage2_single.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8547852/315935) (see [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8436273/315935) too). If you changes the width of some column and then reload the full page you will see that the grid will be created using the widths of column which the used made at the last time. Is it not close to your requirements?