# Change only jqGrid Subgrid header styles

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, subgrid

I've `jqgrid` and `Grid as Subgrid`. I want to have different header style (say background color) for only subgrid.

I've tried to change `.ui-jqgrid-htable,.ui-widget-header` classes,but it's impacting  both main grid and subgrid headers.

How can I only change subgrid header styles?

[image]

Comment: you write about "header style". Do you mean grid header (title, caption see the picture [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:how_it_works)) or column headers? By the way you can create subgrid without the caption (grid title) at all. I personally prefer the way to save the place.

Comment: Header layer(column header). I don't have caption for subgrid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `background` CSS style on `.ui-jqgrid .subgrid-data .ui-th-column` for example to overwrite default background image and background color used in the column headers.

For example [the following demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/StyleOfColumnHeaderInSubgrid.htm) just remove the default background image and set `yellow` as the background color with respect of the following CSS

```css
.ui-jqgrid .subgrid-data .ui-th-column { background: yellow }
```

The results look like on the picture below

[image]

**UPDATED**: One can consider to *remove* the column headers from subgrid at all. It could be interesting for example in case when the subgrid have only one column (one can use `autowidth: true` option in the subgrid additionally) or in case when subgrid have *the same column headers* like the main grid. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14159984/315935) for more information.

Comment: How can I change the subGrid header text color ?