# jqgrid treegrid with level headers

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I Have a TreeGrid with multiple levels I want to **add Header for each level** (i.e similar to that of subgrid, but i dont want to use it as the columns of subgrid doesnt align with the outer grid).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to drive Porsche for free and that somebody should pay for the fuel additionally. :-) I think it's better that you use *existing* features of *existing* product if you want to use free products.

TreeGrid if jqGrid is the kind of grid. If the user collapse node the corresponding rows will be just made hidden. So *the grid* has column headers and no additional header can be created for *tree node*.

On the other side Subgrid, especially [grid as subgrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:subgrid_as_grid), is more flexible. If you create subgrid inside of `subGridRowExpanded` callback you are free to set alignment, width or just everything from the child grid. You can even place any custom HTML an place of subgrid (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SubGrid.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4115481/315935)). In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14265456/315935) you will find an example how one can adjust width of subgrid if the column of main grid are resized.

So I think that you have to use grid as subgrid to implement your requirements. In any ways you should to write some additional code which implements your exact requirements.

Comment: thank you @oleg il try to align the widths for grid as subgrid