# JqGrid - Multiple subgrid at the same level

Tags: jqgrid, subgrid

Can anyone point to multiple subgrid at the same level demo or  example . I have already looked at http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnet.aspx. I'm looking for something in javascript.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not clear what you mean. All examples of subgrid create subgrids on the top level. What you mean?

Comment: I'm looking for loading 2 subgrid at the same level from the main grid.

Comment: To clarify more I'm looking for something like http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnet.aspx. --->Hierarchy--->multiple subgrid at the same level.

Answer (score 3):

[The demo](http://www.trirand.net/examples/grid/hierarchy/several_subgrids/default.aspx) from the trirand.net shows just the following

[image]

It's very easy to create the subgrids like on above picture. You should just understand how the technique [Subgrid as Grid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:subgrid_as_grid) works.

If the user click on "Expand" ("+") icon jqGrid create empty new row below of the expanding. The row (`<tr>`) will get the class `"ui-subgrid"`. Inside of the row jqGrid create two `<td>` elements one `td.subgrid-cell` and another `td.subgrid-data` with the main subgrid information. jqGrid assign `colspan` so that the `<td>` will be extended till the last column of the grid. Inside of the `td.subgrid-data` jqGrid create **empty `div.tablediv`**. The empty div get unique `id` attribute which will be constructed from the id of the grid id, the character "_" and id of expanding row.

The next step is the mostly important. jqGrid call `subGridRowExpanded` callback. The first parameter of the callback is the `id` of empty `<div>` (the `div.tablediv`) where "subgrid" content should be placed. Instead of `<table>` element one can place **any other HTML fragmant** . See [the old demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SubGrid.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4115481/315935). So to create "multiple subgrid at the same level" one need just place two `<table>` element with some unique ids and use jqGrid to create grids on place of the tables.

Comment: The Demo link has a server error...

Comment: @IlludiumPu36: I'm not owner of www.trirand.net and I can't fix the link, but the picture contains all what one need to know. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SubGrid.htm) referenced at the end of my answer provide all what one need to know. jqGrid create empty `<div>` where *any* "subgrid" information could be displayed. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27487764/315935) for additional information.