# Is there any way to start subgrid with particular column of main grid or can we shift subgrid icon column postion?

Tags: jqgrid

Please see my below jqgrid subgrid image,

[image]

Question 1 : By default, my sub grid start with parent grid column "ID" (first column of parent grid), Can we start my sub grid from 3rd column of my parent grid (Contact Name)?

Question 2 : Or, Is there any chance to move sub grid icon **(+)** column  after 2nd column of my parent grid, hence my sub grid will start with 3rd column of my parent grid?

Please suggest, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row with the standard subgrid like on the picture below

[image]

consist from three parts which I marked in different colors. The corresponding HTML structure looks like on the next picture

[image]

jqGrid creates an empty `<div>` (see `<div class="tablediv" id="list_1"></div>` marked in red) and calls `subGridRowExpanded` callback with the id of the div ("list_1" on the picture above) as the value of the first parameter. One places an empty `<table>` with some unique `id` attribute in the div with and creates grid from the `<table>`. The typical code looks like

```js
subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridId, rowid) {
    var $table = $("<table id='" + subgridId + "_t'></table>");
    $("#" + subgridId).append($table);
    $table.jqGrid({
        // ...
    });
}
```

What you can to do is to set some CSS attributes on the `<div>` to place the table on the place where you need it. For example I have the column `"sequence"` in the parent grid of the demo used on the pictures. The header of the column of the header have `gridId + "_sequence"` id. So one can use the following code to set `padding-left` to skip the first column:

```js
subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridId, rowid) {
    var $table = $("<table id='" + subgridId + "_t'></table>");
    $("#" + subgridId).append($table)
        // set padding-left to the outer width of the first column "sequence"
        // of the parent grid
        .css("padding-left", $("#" + this.id + "_sequence").outerWidth() + "px");
    $table.jqGrid({
        // ...
        autowidth: true
    });
}
```

The advantage of the usage `padding-left`: one can use `autowidth: true` in the subgrid to resize the subgrid to fill the right part of the row of subgrid.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SubgridInTheSecondColumn.htm) uses the code. The results looks like on the picture below

[image]

You can change other attributes of subgrid row inside of `subGridRowExpanded` to achieve your exact goals.

Comment: this means, we can't shift the plus column, here plus column is the  2nd column because of we are showing row number as a first column right?

Comment: @user2994834: You should not change the position of "subgrid" column. Instead of that you can make expand/collapse the subgrid on click on any place in the row of the parent grid. [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ExpandSubgridOnSelection0.htm) which I created for [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19970683/315935) shows how to expand/collapse the subgrid on select the row (see `toggleSubGridRow` inside of `onSelectRow`). Look at [one more demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SubgridInTheSecondColumn2.htm) which I made for you and try to select the row.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, I like [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SubgridInTheSecondColumn2.htm),but can we show plus icon near to "Name" column data (myfirstchapter, mysecondchapter) and when click the row can we change plus to minus icon? Thanks!